# ActiveX on Visual C++ 6 Tutorial

Tags: activex, visual-c++-6

I have to build an application based in an ActiveX library (MIL for Matrox framegrabbers).
The library should be already working, since it compiles and run a console application provided as example. (Yes, the console application is probably not using any ActiveX at all... I actually don't know)

The application will set times, frames per second, etc.

I never used Visual C++ before (I have some poor C programming skills), let alone an ActiveX library. I'm not even able to get an "Ok Cancel" dialog to work...

**I need the most basic ever vc6 + ActiveX tutorial.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/tutorials/article.php/c17) is an example - how to create a control (you already have one) and how to interact with it.

By the way, using VC++ isn't the best choice IMO. Programming of COM clients are much simpler in VB...